# how to display a timer in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

hey i am making a program which records desktop screen.

So what i want to do is when ever i click on my start button(tkinter Gui) in my gui window.

It should start a timer like 3.... ,2.... ,1.... in big font directly on my desktop screen and not on my tkinter window. and then my function should start.

How can i do that ..

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("our program")
start_cap =tk.button(text='start recording' command=start_capute)
start_cap.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Not mentioning the functions and the entire code here as not necessary the code is working fine and i just want to add a new feature of the timer in it.

Comment: There are dozens of questions on this site related to timers and clocks. Have you done any research before asking the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk
# from tkinter import *

def Start():

    def Count(Number):
        if Number == -1:
            win.withdraw()
            print("Start") # what you want to do
            return False
        NumberLabel["text"] = Number
        win.after(1000,Count,Number-1)
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.geometry("+%d+%d"%((screen_width-win.winfo_width())/2,(screen_height-win.winfo_height())/2)) # make it in the center.
    win.overrideredirect(1)
    win.wm_attributes('-topmost',1) # top window
    win.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor',win['bg']) # background transparent.
    NumberLabel = tk.Label(win,font=("",40,"bold"),fg='white')
    NumberLabel.pack()
    win.after(0,lambda :Count(3))
    win.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("our program")
start_cap = tk.Button(text='start recording',command=Start)
start_cap.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No need to use global `Number`.  Pass it as an argument to `Count()`.

Comment: Use `win.after(1000, Count, Number-1)` instead of lambda and `Number -= 1`.